# Python argument parsing from bash variable

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to pass a bash variable to be parsed by a python script, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

command="--var1 var1 --var2 'var 2'"
echo $command
python test.py $command
```

python script (test.py)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--var1", action="store", dest="var1")
parser.add_argument("--var2", action="store", dest="var2")

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.var1, args.var2
```

However, it fails due to there being whitespace, which I'm not sure how to escape `error: unrecognized arguments: 2'`. Running `python test.py --var1 var1 --var2 'var 2'` from the command line works fine though. Is there any way around this?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you do not need the `action` and `store` in this simple case, the variables will be created by the parser implicitly (as names of your options), so this should be enough:
`parser.add_argument("--var1")` and 
`parser.add_argument("--var2")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arrays to store multi-word strings. Regular string variables suffer from unavoidable whitespace and quoting problems whereas arrays handle them without issue.

```sh
command=(--var1 var1 --var2 'var 2')
echo "${command[@]}"
python test.py "${command[@]}"
```

`"${command[@]}"` is the syntax for expanding an array while preserving each element as a separate word. Make sure to use the quotes; don't leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an expansion without quotes, bash expands it, including any glob expansions or other things found within. It also wrecks any whitespace. This is why using quotes is [so very recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

In other words, by the time the arguments get to python, they're already wordsplit, and can't be put back together.

If you need to put a set of arguments in a name, consider using an array, like

```
command=('--var1' 'var1' '--var2' 'var 2')
```

and the expansion like

```
python test.py "${command[@]}"
```

Using an array, bash will respect the argument setup just like it was in the array.